# Express cross domain cookies

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

How to set a cross-domain cookie and redirect in express ??

```
res.cookie('token' ,'token');
res.cookie('id', 'id');
res.redirect(301, 'https://example.com');
```

This is the code i am using but it is not working

Comment: there is no such thing like cross-domain cookies!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)